# which is correct, if or whether?

Tags: if-whether

Given the widespread use of emoticons in electronic communication,
an important question is **[if / whether]** they help internet users to understand emotions in online communication.

Is the usage of "if" correct in this case?

Comment: No, not really here. It's not ungrammatical, but right after _an important question is_, one expects an embedded question, and that's what _whether_ is for. It's the _wh_-word for embedded yes/no questions. That's why _whether_ and _if_ can often be swapped -- both imply only two choices, yes or no. _Call me if/whether you see her or not_ works fine, but not here.